# Google Maps API - Map Is Not Loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to embed a google map in my site , but with not much success.
I've used the next code section: (i'm using an actual api key on my own computer)

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myapikey&sensor=true">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

inside `<body>` section i've added `<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 40%; height: 40%"></div>`

How could I handle this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like problem with api key, try to remove that from URL

Comment: As i've mentioned in the post - i've got an api key , just replaced it with "myapikey" for the post

Comment: use the chrome dev tools to see if the maps js files are loaded, if yes then use debug tool and set the break point in map var and make sure the object is created.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Specify the canvas' width and height as absolute lengths rather than `%`.

For example :

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 300px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Alternatively, stick with `%` for the canvas but put it inside a container with width and height specified as absolute lengths.

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:800px;">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 40%; height: 40%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: We've got a winner :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In case you don`t want to fix your size to absolute width and height in px, ensure that all parent tags have height 100%

for example html -> body -> some_ids -> map-id

All of them have height and width in %

ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial