# Issues with Google Map and 100% height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue getting the height to adjust so that the map will actually appear - I know that I have to set the html and body height to 100% (which I did) and the parent div to 100% (hence the .info div having 100% height) but for some reason it's still not rendering the map properly - the width works fine, but the height doesn't.

I've included a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAceA/3/) to demonstrate what I mean.

These are the styles I have so far (not including the javascript)

> Address & Phone
>
> ```
> <div class="mapWrapper">
>     <div id="map-canvas"></div>
> </div> </div>
> ```

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
}
.mapWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
    width: 65%;
    height: 65%;
    min-height: 65%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 3px solid #355868;
}
.info {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Your map doesn't seem to load. Try specifying the canvas' width and height as absolute lengths rather than %.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15700550/google-maps-api-map-is-not-loaded

Comment: Strangely enough, it loads perfectly fine on my localhost server, and using em values rather than percentages got it working fine.  I guess that'll fix this issue :D

Comment: Great (y) Go ahead, answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you've a syntax error in your CSS selector: `}.mapWrapper { ... }` Remove the first closing curly brace before the `.mapWrapper` class, And it would work.

So the CSS engine ignores the `.mapWrapper { ... }` rules and `.mapWrapper` element *(which is the parent of `.map-canvas`)*, wont't have an explicit `height` value.

Hence, according to spec *[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)*, for the `height` property:

> The `percentage` is calculated with respect to the `height` of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the `height` of the containing
>   block **is not specified explicitly** (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to **auto**. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/bAceA/8/)**.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering - using em's over percentages did in fact allow the height to properly adjust.  Not entirely sure if that requires you to set the height of parent elements, but all I did was change 100% to an em value, and it worked.